# Showing widget demo in mobile view

Tags: jquery, .net, html, css, mobile

I am creating a intranet application to my company which contains different plugins developed by us or commonly used plugins. It is a responsive design. Now I have a new requirement to show the widget demos in different mobile devices like iphone, android etc.

My lead show me [this example](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/mobiledemos/jqxgrid/index.htm?(android)#demos/jqxgrid/grid.htm)

Based on the device selection we need to show plugins in different devices.
For example I have a widget named datatable, I need to enable different views for this. How can i achieve it.
I dont have any idea how to implement it. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested solution depends on the objective of your widget demos. Some proposed solutions for various situation are as follow. State your real need precisely if you need more information.

### Objective 1: To demonstrate the look and feel of the widget in different devices based on their screen size in a technical presentation.

One of the most convenient way is to use the [Device Mode and Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) in Google Chrome's Devtools. It allows you to preview the layout by emulating different screen sizes and resolutions.

### Objective 2: To allow non-technical users to preview the widget in a beautiful emulator.

You may consider to use third party solution such as [mobiletest.me](http://mobiletest.me/). This kind of paid service probably may save plenty of your development cost.

### Objective 3: We need to develop our own solution anyway

If your team insists to implement it, consider to use an `iframe` to separate your page and the widget demo. Use `background-image` to place an image of the emulator behind your widget. Use `padding` or `position` to place your widget at a proper position.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all, no need for jQWidgets DataGrid. It is an overhead for this small application.

Instead I would suggest you to use only the bootstrap grid (not full bootstrap library). You can download [this css file](https://github.com/zirafa/bootstrap-grid-only/blob/master/css/grid12.css).

Now that you have the grid in place, you can use `col-*-*` to create your appropriate layout and this will work in all devices.